# Automated convert string into date

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdateformatter

How can I automated convert string to date with this code

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"

    guard let date = dateFormatter.date(from: String) else { return }
```

so I don't have to type again or reuse again, I was thinking with DateFormatter extension but I don't know how or is that the correct method. Thank you for your attention

Comment: Do you need only hours and min from date object?

Comment: What do you mean by _automated convert_ ?

Comment: @HPM I need to convert to date because I got a string time like "12:00"

Comment: @ShubhamBakshi I have a 5 different time of string like this for example"12:00", "14:00" etc. so if I format it and convert it into date by typing over and over is not effective

Comment: Create a function that take a _string date_ as input and provide the output as a _Date date_ ? OR you can create an extension of `String` class and create _function_ with name like `convertToDate()` and use that !

Comment: @ferryawijayanto Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/53474848/10661965

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create extension on `String` instead of `Dateformatter`.

Try with below code,

```
extension String {

    var date: Date? {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        return dateFormatter.date(from: self)
    }

}
```

Uses example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        let dateString = "11:32"
        if let date = dateString.date { //This will return Date object
            debugPrint(date)
        }

        let invalidDateString = "XYZ:ABC"
        if let invalidDate = invalidDateString.date { //This will return nil as date string is invalid
            debugPrint(invalidDate)
        }
    }
```